# Increment value inside Firestore using a batch - "Ambiguous use of 'increment'"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I simply would like to `increment` a `value` inside my **Cloud-Firestore** but I can not get it done and can't find any solutions in the docs..

This is what I tried:

```
let batch = db.batch()

// Set username and uid for user
let userRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(userID)

batch.updateData(["population": FieldValue.increment(1)], forDocument: userRef)
```

But this gives me this `error`:

> Ambiguous use of 'increment'

What's the right way to get this done? Is this actually possible with `batch`?

**Update:** The reason I would like to use `batch` is that inside the function I need to update some other fields as well.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can try this:

```
let batch = db.batch()

let userRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(userID);

batch.update(userRef, "population", firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1));
```

Firestore docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions